# How do I get the part of the url after the `?` in window.location

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem in JS. `window.location.href` shows the full location of a URL. `window.location.hostname` shows the hostname. `window.location.pathname` shows the path. but what `code` do I need to use for the extension to show. 
**Example** 
URL is `https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_href`

I get

```
window.location.href: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_href
window.location.hostname: www.w3schools.com
window.location.pathname: /js/tryit.asp
what code? = filename=tryjs_loc_href
```

if you don't understand Please see the picture

[image]

My Code is

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The full URL of this page is:<br>" + window.location.href;
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: what does your code produce? By the way, none of the code you posted is valid - since they aren't strings you're attempting to assign

Comment: i need to show the extension in html

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location ? The answer is `window.location.search`

Comment: `i need to show the extension in html` you mean the location ... your code could work

Comment: What you pasted isn’t even valid syntax.

Comment: @AbuNaaimMd.MontasirRahman I've edited the question title to make it clearer. Let me know if this was not your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [URL searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) or just location.search (here also available in the url

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_href")

const search = url.search; // or location.search

console.log(search.slice(1)); // remove the ?

console.log(url.searchParams.get("filename")); // or get just the filename
```

PS: I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) over w3schools any day